# Node.js how do I combine similar objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I combine 2 JavaScript array objects like the following:

**object array 1**

```
[{id:1,name:alan}, {id:3,name:alice}]
```

**object array 2**

```
[{id:4,name:sam}, {id:6,name:ella}]
```

**desired**

```
[{id:1,name:alan}, {id:3,name:alice},
{id:4,name:sam}, {id:6,name:ella}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `concat` to achieve this:

```js
const objectArray1 = [{id:1,name:'alan'}, {id:3,name:'alice'}]
const objectArray2 = [{id:4,name:'sam'}, {id:6,name:'ella'}]

const desired = [].concat(objectArray1, objectArray2)

console.log(desired)
```

One advantage of this approach is greater compatibility compared to alternative methods (ie that rely in modern syntax/language features).

For more information on `concat`, [see the documentation for this method on the Array type at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spread operator `...`.

Also not if `alan`,`alice` etc are not variable you need to put them in quote

```js
let obj1 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'alan'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'alice'
}]


let obj2 = [{
  id: 4,
  name: 'sam'
}, {
  id: 6,
  name: 'ella'
}]

let obj3 = [...obj1, ...obj2];
console.log(obj3)
```

Comment: recommend this answer

Comment: note using the spread operator will not work if this code needs to run on older versions of node or older browsers

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];

console.log(array1.concat(array2));
// expected output: Array ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach to `Array.prototype.concat`, you could use ES6 [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
const a = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'alan'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'alice'
}];
const b = [{
  id: 4,
  name: 'sam'
}, {
  id: 6,
  name: 'ella'
}];

const c = [...a, ...b];
console.log(c);
```